# INSERTing value '000' with PDO results in NULL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having a little trouble getting PDO to work like I need it to work when handling integer value 0.

In a mock order system, `final_status` 0 represents a successfully placed order.  Errors with the order result in a non-zero integer for `final_status`, such as 14, 5, ect.  Incomplete orders need an actual NULL `final_status` value

Here's the example table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `order_status` (
  `order_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `final_status` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_status` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When an order is updated, I'm running into an issue where PDO either sets the `final_status` of 0 to NULL, or sets actual NULL/blank values to 0 (depending on which constant I declare in the bind statement).

So, assuming:

```
$final_status = 0000;
$order_id = 123456;
```

The update query:

```
try
{
    $q = "
        UPDATE
            order_status 
        SET
            final_status = :final_status
        WHERE
            order_id = :order_id 
    ";
    $stmt = $dbx_pdo->prepare($q);
    $stmt->bindValue(':final_status',       !empty($final_status)       ? $final_status     : NULL, PDO::PARAM_NULL);   
    $stmt->bindValue(':order_id',           !empty($order_id)           ? $order_id         : NULL, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->closeCursor();

} catch(PDOException $err) {
    error_handler();
}
```

If I use PARAM_NULL for the first bindParam constant, values of '0000' or blank values are translated to NULL, which creates a false negative.

If I use PARAM_INT, values of '0000' or blank values are translated to 0, which creates a false positive and is bad.

So, is the table definition culprit, or is there a way to do what I want with INT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think (not sure), the problem is because you're using `!empty()`. This will convert `0` to false, which will invalidate the ternary condition. Therefore if `$final_status == 0`, your ternary condition will return null.

Try changing it to:

```
isset($final_status) && $final_status >= 0 ? $final_status : null
```

or

```
is_null($final_status) ? null : (int) $final_status
```

If this answer doesn't work, comment and I'll delete it to avoid future confusion.

Comment: Will test tomorrow afternoon and follow up.

Comment: Here is the bindValue line that ended up doing the trick.   It correctly handles final_status values of 0, whole numbers, and blank values.   `$stmt->bindValue(':final_status',       isset($final_status)       ? $final_status     : NULL, PDO::PARAM_INT); `

Answer (score 3):

from the official documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
The following values are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)

This will return true.

```
<?php
    $final_status = 000;
    echo empty($final_status);
```

Consider using isset instead.

```
$stmt->bindValue(':final_status',       !isset($final_status)       ? $final_status     : NULL, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
```

Comment: Here is the bindValue line that ended up doing the trick.   It correctly handles final_status values of 0, whole numbers, and blank values.   `$stmt->bindValue(':final_status',       isset($final_status)       ? $final_status     : NULL, PDO::PARAM_INT); `